# Compress GIF images using JAI

Tags: compression, gif, javax.imageio, jai

[image: Original GIF Image]
[image: Output GIF Image]

I am compressing the images using JAI (image-io). when i do for GIF image, sometime compression GIF image size more than original image.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fileObject);
 File compressedImageFile = new File("compressed-"+destination.getName());
              OutputStream os =new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);
final ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
final ImageWriter gifWriter = new GIFImageWriter(gifSPI);
final ImageWriteParam iwp = gifWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
iwp.setCompressionType(compression);
iwp.setCompressionQuality(compressionRate);

gifWriter.setOutput(ios);
gifWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), iwp);
System.out.println("After Compression in GIF WRITER >>>>>>> " + ios.length()/1024 );      
ios.flush();
gifWriter.dispose()
```

Any idea?

Comment: What original image? JPEG or PNG or what? Depending on the image, that could be easily the case. Can you provide example pictures?

Comment: Please check the post. I have edited the image. Original image is GIF format. and output also same.

Comment: You can tweak the GIF to fit your image. Take your example image, you basically have 2 colors, maybe 16 or 32 shades of gray. Thus you can modify the palette size accordingly. There are teaks in GIF, but you have to know when they are helpful and when not.

Comment: hi harald,  yes converting gif to jpg doesn't make sense but if i store it as gif it losses it transparency sometime and size is more.that was the reason for storing to jpg. ok fine how to convert it as gif without losing the transparency with 0.75f quality?

Comment: What I meant with doesn't make sense, is that your code can only ever write a GIF, and you also state "Original image is GIF format. and output also same"... But this is not true, and you have code and samples that are not related, which is only going to confuse people trying to help you. Finally, are you sure `0.75f` is a value that makes sense for GIF compression? AFAIK, GIFs are always LZW encoded (it's possible to use a non-compressing LZW-compatible encoding, but it was mostly used to avoid the LZW patent) and it has no "quality" or "rate" setting.